# How to get h4 tags inside a tag with Bootstrap Tab Collapse Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, accordion

I´m using this https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse
to transform tabs to accordion on mobile. But I think on mobile accordion link should be full width. So trying to change this result

```
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="js-tabcollapse-panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" role="tab" aria-controls="same" href="#same-collapse" aria-expanded="true">Some heading</a>
</h4>
</div>
```

into this

```
<div class="panel-heading">
<a class="js-tabcollapse-panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" role="tab" aria-controls="same" href="#same-collapse" aria-expanded="true">
<h4 class="panel-title">
Some heading
</h4>
</a>
</div>
```

I´m stuck with that jQuery append which appends all html. I tried jQuerys wrap function but the plugin is too complicated for me to change. The order of the html and to change the place of the heading text only into h4 tag. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the plugin code.

```
!function ($) {

"use strict";

// TABCOLLAPSE CLASS DEFINITION
// ======================

var TabCollapse = function (el, options) {
    this.options   = options;
    this.$tabs  = $(el);

    this._accordionVisible = false; //content is attached to tabs at first
    this._initAccordion();
    this._checkStateOnResize();


    // checkState() has gone to setTimeout for making it possible to attach listeners to
    // shown-accordion.bs.tabcollapse event on page load.
    // See https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse/issues/23
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.checkState();
    }, 0);
};

TabCollapse.DEFAULTS = {
    accordionClass: 'visible-xs',
    tabsClass: 'hidden-xs',
    accordionTemplate: function(heading, groupId, parentId, active) {
        return  '<div class="panel panel-default">' +
                '   <div class="panel-heading">' +
                '      <h4 class="panel-title">' +
                '      </h4>' +
                '   </div>' +
                '   <div id="' + groupId + '" class="panel-collapse collapse ' + (active ? 'in' : '') + '">' +
                '       <div class="panel-body js-tabcollapse-panel-body">' +
                '       </div>' +
                '   </div>' +
                '</div>'

    }
};

TabCollapse.prototype.checkState = function(){
    if (this.$tabs.is(':visible') && this._accordionVisible){
        this.showTabs();
        this._accordionVisible = false;
    } else if (this.$accordion.is(':visible') && !this._accordionVisible){
        this.showAccordion();
        this._accordionVisible = true;
    }
};

TabCollapse.prototype.showTabs = function(){
    var view = this;
    this.$tabs.trigger($.Event('show-tabs.bs.tabcollapse'));

    var $panelHeadings = this.$accordion.find('.js-tabcollapse-panel-heading').detach();

    $panelHeadings.each(function() {
        var $panelHeading = $(this),
        $parentLi = $panelHeading.data('bs.tabcollapse.parentLi');

        var $oldHeading = view._panelHeadingToTabHeading($panelHeading);

        $parentLi.removeClass('active');
        if ($parentLi.parent().hasClass('dropdown-menu') && !$parentLi.siblings('li').hasClass('active')) {
            $parentLi.parent().parent().removeClass('active');
        }

        if (!$oldHeading.hasClass('collapsed')) {
            $parentLi.addClass('active');
            if ($parentLi.parent().hasClass('dropdown-menu')) {
                $parentLi.parent().parent().addClass('active');
            }
        } else {
            $oldHeading.removeClass('collapsed');
        }

        $parentLi.append($panelHeading);
    });

    if (!$('li').hasClass('active')) {
        $('li').first().addClass('active')
    }

    var $panelBodies = this.$accordion.find('.js-tabcollapse-panel-body');
    $panelBodies.each(function(){
        var $panelBody = $(this),
            $tabPane = $panelBody.data('bs.tabcollapse.tabpane');
        $tabPane.append($panelBody.contents().detach());
    });
    this.$accordion.html('');

    if(this.options.updateLinks) {
        var $tabContents = this.getTabContentElement();
        $tabContents.find('[data-toggle-was="tab"], [data-toggle-was="pill"]').each(function() {
            var $el = $(this);
            var href = $el.attr('href').replace(/-collapse$/g, '');
            $el.attr({
                'data-toggle': $el.attr('data-toggle-was'),
                'data-toggle-was': '',
                'data-parent': '',
                href: href
            });
        });
    }

    this.$tabs.trigger($.Event('shown-tabs.bs.tabcollapse'));
};

TabCollapse.prototype.getTabContentElement = function(){
    var $tabContents = $(this.options.tabContentSelector);
    if($tabContents.length === 0) {
        $tabContents = this.$tabs.siblings('.tab-content');
    }
    return $tabContents;
};

TabCollapse.prototype.showAccordion = function(){
    this.$tabs.trigger($.Event('show-accordion.bs.tabcollapse'));

    var $headings = this.$tabs.find('li:not(.dropdown) [data-toggle="tab"], li:not(.dropdown) [data-toggle="pill"]'),
        view = this;
    $headings.each(function(){
        var $heading = $(this),
            $parentLi = $heading.parent();
        $heading.data('bs.tabcollapse.parentLi', $parentLi);
        view.$accordion.append(view._createAccordionGroup(view.$accordion.attr('id'), $heading.detach()));
    });

    if(this.options.updateLinks) {
        var parentId = this.$accordion.attr('id');
        var $selector = this.$accordion.find('.js-tabcollapse-panel-body');
        $selector.find('[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]').each(function() {
            var $el = $(this);
            var href = $el.attr('href') + '-collapse';
            $el.attr({
                'data-toggle-was': $el.attr('data-toggle'),
                'data-toggle': 'collapse',
                'data-parent': '#' + parentId,
                href: href
            });
        });
    }

    this.$tabs.trigger($.Event('shown-accordion.bs.tabcollapse'));
};

TabCollapse.prototype._panelHeadingToTabHeading = function($heading) {
    var href = $heading.attr('href').replace(/-collapse$/g, '');
    $heading.attr({
        'data-toggle': 'tab',
        'href': href,
        'data-parent': ''
    });
    return $heading;
};

TabCollapse.prototype._tabHeadingToPanelHeading = function($heading, groupId, parentId, active) {
    $heading.addClass('js-tabcollapse-panel-heading ' + (active ? '' : 'collapsed'));
    $heading.attr({
        'data-toggle': 'collapse',
        'data-parent': '#' + parentId,
        'href': '#' + groupId
    });
    return $heading;
};

TabCollapse.prototype._checkStateOnResize = function(){
    var view = this;
    $(window).resize(function(){
        clearTimeout(view._resizeTimeout);
        view._resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            view.checkState();
        }, 100);
    });
};


TabCollapse.prototype._initAccordion = function(){
    var randomString = function() {
        var result = "",
            possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            result += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }
        return result;
    };

    var srcId = this.$tabs.attr('id'),
        accordionId = (srcId ? srcId : randomString()) + '-accordion';

    this.$accordion = $('<div class="panel-group ' + this.options.accordionClass + '" id="' + accordionId +'"></div>');
    this.$tabs.after(this.$accordion);
    this.$tabs.addClass(this.options.tabsClass);
    this.getTabContentElement().addClass(this.options.tabsClass);
};

TabCollapse.prototype._createAccordionGroup = function(parentId, $heading){
    var tabSelector = $heading.attr('data-target'),
        active = $heading.data('bs.tabcollapse.parentLi').is('.active');

    if (!tabSelector) {
        tabSelector = $heading.attr('href');
        tabSelector = tabSelector && tabSelector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, ''); //strip for ie7
    }

    var $tabPane = $(tabSelector),
        groupId = $tabPane.attr('id') + '-collapse',
        $panel = $(this.options.accordionTemplate($heading, groupId, parentId, active));
    $panel.find('.panel-heading > .panel-title').append(this._tabHeadingToPanelHeading($heading, groupId, parentId, active));
    $panel.find('.panel-body').append($tabPane.contents().detach())
        .data('bs.tabcollapse.tabpane', $tabPane);

    return $panel;
};



// TABCOLLAPSE PLUGIN DEFINITION
// =======================

$.fn.tabCollapse = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this   = $(this);
        var data    = $this.data('bs.tabcollapse');
        var options = $.extend({}, TabCollapse.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option === 'object' && option);

        if (!data) $this.data('bs.tabcollapse', new TabCollapse(this, options));
    });
};

$.fn.tabCollapse.Constructor = TabCollapse;
}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Consider adding your javascript as well. See what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, and you'll increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Plugin code added.

Comment: Nesting a H4 inside an A Tag is invalid HTML. Displaying the A as a block Element with full width is a question of CSS not of nesting, for example by using: .panel-title a {display: block;}

Comment: @axel.michel If I have understood correctly the case is not invalid HTML. [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html) . But your comment solved my problem, which apparently was not even a problem :) . Just wondering how could have I missed that {display: block;}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@axel.michel Your comment solved my problem, which apparently was not even a problem :) . I´m going with CSS.

> Nesting a H4 inside an A Tag is invalid HTML. Displaying the A as a block Element with full width is a question of CSS not of nesting, for example by using: .panel-title a {display: block;} – axel.michel